# In Python, how can I check if an array contains all elements of another array/list, including duplicates?

Tags: python, arrays

There appear to be several ways to determine if a set is a subset of another set, but I haven't been able to find something concise that determines whether all elements of a list (or array), including duplicate values, appear in another list (or array). For example, for the hypothetical function `contains_all(A, B)` which checks whether all elements of `B` are contained in `A`, these are some expected outputs:

`contains_all([11, 4, 11, 6], [6, 11])` returns `True` (order doesn't matter)

`contains_all([11, 4, 11, 6], [11, 9])` returns `False` (no 9)

`contains_all([11, 4, 11, 6], [11, 11])` returns `True`

`contains_all([11, 4, 11, 6], [11, 11, 11])` returns `False` (only two 11's)

`contains_all([11, 4, 11, 6], [6, 6])` returns `False` (only one 6)

`contains_all([11, 4, 11, 6], [11, 4, 6, 11])` returns `True`

`contains_all([11, 4, 11, 6], [11, 4, 11, 6, 5])` returns `False` (no 5)

The fourth and fifth examples above, specifically, are what I'm having trouble implementing. `set(B).issubset(A)` or list comprehensions cover the other cases, but not these, since sets don't have duplicate elements. Is there a concise way to do this? If not, what would be the best way to approach writing a function that does this? It seems something like this may be possible with collections.Counter objects or multisets, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, `collections.Counter` is a good way to go. You just need to go over the `B` counter and check if the the value is smaller or equal. Do it in `all()` to check all the key-value pairs

```
def contains_all(a, b):
    counter_a = Counter(a)
    counter_b = Counter(b)
    return all(v <= counter_a[k] for k, v in counter_b.items())
```

**Edit**

[user2357112 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73397616/5168011) is much nicer, but apply to Pyton3.10 or newer. For older versions you can use this answer.

Comment: `collections.Counter` reports a count of 0 for elements with no count associated, so you don't need the `k in counter_a` check.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, I guess I'm not that familiar with `Counter`.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.10, `collections.Counter` has this functionality built-in:

```
def contains_all(A, B):
    return Counter(A) >= Counter(B)
```

However, due to supporting negative counts, `>=` needs to [iterate over all keys in both counters](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L737-L741), which is inefficient when you know all counts are nonnegative. Manually checking just the keys from the B counter (as in [Guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73397515/in-python-how-can-i-check-if-an-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array-li/73397588#73397588)) should be faster. (I don't have a Python 3.10 handy, so I can't provide timings.)

Comment: Is this version specific? on Python 3.9 I'm getting `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Counter' and 'Counter'`

Comment: @Guy: Apparently it is! I thought it was much older, but the docs say it's new in 3.10.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def contains(A, B):
contains_all = []
data_missing = []
for i in B:
    if i in A and B.count(i) <= A.count(i):
        contains_all.append(i)
    else:
        data_missing.append(i)
if data_missing:
    return False
else:
    return True

>>> print(contains([11, 4, 11, 6], [11, 4, 11, 6, 5]))
>>> False
```